# What is correct way to implement in memory queue in Scala, that support poll(n) functionality?

Tags: scala, queue

What is correct way to implement in memory thread-safe queue in Scala, that support poll(n) functionality? So i could give a number, and get subset of queue. All elements returned should also be removed from original queue.

Queue.splitAt(n) do excatly what I need, but looks very inefficient as it just iterate through all elements:
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala

```
def splitAt(n: Int): (Repr, Repr) = {
  val l, r = newBuilder
  l.sizeHintBounded(n, this)
   if (n >= 0) r.sizeHint(this, -n)
   var i = 0
   for (x <- this) {
    (if (i < n) l else r) += x
    i += 1
  }
  (l.result, r.result)
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the queue to be a mutable or immutable type?

Comment: Mutable, as it is a queue, and could be modified in parallel (enqueue/poll operations at same time).

Comment: So you need it to be thread-safe?

Comment: Yes, thread-safe. Just added to OP.

Comment: What prevents you from doing poll() n times? Do you need to ensure the n items you get were next to each other on the queue?

Comment: But then I need to add them to new collection one by one... I thought there should be some more convenient way :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't mind that concurrent calls to `poll(n)` may interleave their underlying `poll()` calls, the following might work for you:

```
import java.util.Queue
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

implicit class QueueExtensions[T](q: Queue[T]) {

  def poll(n: Int, acc: List[T] = List.empty): List[T] = n match {
    case 0 => acc
    case c =>
      val item = q.poll()
      if (item == null)//queue is empty
        acc
      else
        poll(n-1, acc :+ item)
  }
}

val queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue[Int]()
(1 to 10) foreach {queue.add(_)}
val f1 = Future(queue.poll(3))
val f2 = Future(queue.poll(4))
val output = for{
  l1 <- f1
  l2 <- f2
}yield{
  val s1 = l1.foldLeft("List 1:")((str, v) => str + " " + v)
  val s2 = l2.foldLeft(" List 2: ")((str, v) => str + " " + v) 
  s1 + "\n" + s2
}
println(Await.result(output, 3 seconds))
```

To see what I mean by interleaving, you might need to temporarily edit the `poll(n)` to:

```
def poll(n: Int, acc: List[T] = List.empty): List[T] = n match {
    case 0 => acc
    case c =>
      Thread.sleep(10)
      val item = q.poll()
      if (item == null)//queue is empty
        acc
      else
        poll(n-1, acc :+ item)
  }
```